# Post the comment on any wall of Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook

I am using Facebook sdk, (https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/) to show the NewsFeed. I can be show the all newsfeed wall in my application.

Now I need to send the comment on the any wall which is visible by me. And how I can be like the wall and the comment through my application. Can anybody plz help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to comment on the actual wall? Like Juicy Scripter pointed out below, I think you can only comment on a post (the wall being a collection of posts). Can you provide any clarifications (preferably before the bounty ends)?

Comment: @ dstricks, I want to be like any wall and comment also. And the given code is not sufficient for this.

Comment: You should clarify what exactly you want and do your own homework too, help us help you, not just ask us to provide final code for you. What did you to get desired functionality? Maybe reading [ask] is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be clear:

- you can only *comment* on **posts** (not the actual wall itself)
- you can only *like* a **comment** or **post** (not the actual wall itself)

Using the Facebook SDK you can do the following for comments:

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
String commentText = "I love blu-ray";
String postId = "7568536355_333422146668093"; //a lifehacker post about blu-ray

String graphPath = postId + "/comments";
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", commentText);
facebook.request(graphPath, params, "POST");
```

... and the following for likes:

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
String postId = "7568536355_333422146668093"; //a lifehacker post about blu-ray

String graphPath = postId + "/likes";
facebook.request(graphPath, new Bundle(), "POST");
```

Comment: :: How can i get postId ?

Answer (score 0):

You should get familiar with [Facebook Android SDK usage of Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#graph), [Post object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) (comments connection) and [Comment Object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/) Graph API documentation (likes section).

- You can't comment on the wall itself but on one of the posts.
- You can post on the wall via Graph API
- You can comment on post via Graph API
- You can create likes for both Posts and Comments via Graph API

**Update:**

Example below about creating comment and liking it (samples of how to create comment for post and like the post already shown in other answer to this question):

```
// I assume you already have post_id (which is constructed from USERID_MESSAGEID)
Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("message", "This is a comment text");
String comment_id = facebook.request(post_id + "/comments", params, "POST");

// Once you have comment_id it can be used for liking it.
facebook.request(comment_id + "/likes", new Bundle(), "POST");
```

Comment: :: how can i get postId?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse all feeds using graph api by passing

```
mAsyncRunner.request("me/home", params, new graphApiRequestListener());
```

it returns you json data with all your post and comments and likes 
you can parse that data get all commnets

for further information search for hackbook  for android example

Answer (score -1):

```
 'Use Facebook Api as library download api and use it as library'







    private static final String FACEBOOK_APPID = "Your Api key";

                Facebook facebook = new Facebook(FACEBOOK_APPID);

      facebook.authorize(this,new String[] { "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream" },
                             new DialogListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                                    postImageonWall();
                                    try {
                                        facebook.logout(TestActivity.this);

                                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    // finish();

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onError(DialogError e) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancel() {

                                }
```

use postImageOnWall method

```
            public void postImageonWall() {

                    byte[] data = null;

                    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                    data = baos.toByteArray();
                AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
                    mAsyncRunner.request(null, params, "POST", new RequestListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                                Object state) {
                            Log.d("MalformedURLException", e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                            Log.d("onIOException", e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                                Object state) {
                            Log.d("FileNotFoundException", e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                            Log.d("onFacebookError", e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                            Log.d("onComplete", response);
                        }
                    }, null);

                }
```

Comment: This is not the answer of my question. Because I want to be comment on any wall and like the wall and comment. Posting wall is not my purpose, I already do this.